# Unable to send log event in html Firebase Analytics

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-analytics

**Firebase analytics problem in JS**

Hello I am unable to send lo event in my html and js website.

**My code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>


<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "my data",
    authDomain: "my data",
    databaseURL: "my data",
    projectId: "my data",
    storageBucket: "my data",
    messagingSenderId: "my data",
    appId: "my data",
    measurementId: "my data"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  
 analytics.logEvent('test_event', { name: 'hiii'});
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: analytics.logEvent is not a function
    at event.php:25:12
```

So now how can i solve it?
Maybe i am missing something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the modular implementation, you should import `logEvent` from the analytics module

```
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";
```

and send the analytics instance as the first parameter [LogEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/analytics#logevent)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
      import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "my data",
        authDomain: "my data",
        databaseURL: "my data",
        projectId: "my data",
        storageBucket: "my data",
        messagingSenderId: "my data",
        appId: "my data",
        measurementId: "my data"
      };
    
      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      
     logEvent(analytics ,'test_event', { name: 'hiii'});
     
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Searched for hours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may check and initialize Firebase Analytics like this:

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app')
require('firebase/analytics')

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics();
```